# Spark 1.6 Dataframe cache not working correctly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My understanding is that if I have a dataframe if I cache() it and trigger an action like `df.take(1)` or df.count() it should compute the dataframe and save it in memory, And whenever that cached dataframe is called in the program it uses already computed dataframe from cache.

but that is not how my program is working.

I have a dataframe like below which I am caching it, and then immediately I run a `df.count` action.

1. `val df = inputDataFrame.select().where().withColumn("newcol" , "").cache()`
2. `df.count`

When I run the program. In Spark UI I see that  first line runs for 4 min and 
when it comes to second line it again runs 4 min basically first line is re computed twice?

Shouldn't first line computed and cached when second line triggers?

how to resolve this behavior. I am stuck, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that if I have a dataframe if I cache() it and trigger an action like df.take(1) or df.count() it should compute the dataframe and save it in memory,

It is not correct. Simple `cache` and `count` (`take` wouldn't work on RDD either) is a valid method for RDDs but it is not the case with `Datasets`, which use much more advanced optimizations. With query:

```
df.select(...).where(...).withColumn("newcol" , "").count()
```

any column, which is not used in `where` clause can be ignored.

There is an important [discussion on the developer list](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Will-count-always-trigger-an-evaluation-of-each-row-td21018.html#a21019) and quoting [Sean Owen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64174/sean-owen)

> I think the right answer is "don't do that" but if you really had to you could trigger a Dataset operation that does nothing per partition. I presume that would be more reliable because the whole partition has to be computed to make it available in practice. Or, go so far as to loop over every element.

Translated to code:

```
df.foreach(_ => ())
```

There is

```
df.registerAsTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("CACHE TABLE df")
```

which is eager but it is no longer (Spark 2 and forward) documented and should be avoided.

Comment: Hi Alper, I have a list of dataframes: df1, df2, df3. each is the result of join, groupby and transformations . I join them step by step into a single  df. When I run it, I see that to compute df it always compute df1, df2, df3 at once which cause larage disk shuflling usage. I tried to force Spark to materialise df1, df2, df3 before  creating df using either save/load, cache.count, persist.count or df.rdd.count, but only the first solution work. In the first solution I need to save dataframes to a temp location and load them. Do you have another solutions that not require to save/load?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you call `cache` on a DataFrame it's not cached in this moment, it's only "marked" for potential future caching. The actual caching is only done when an action is followed later. You can also see your cached DataFrame in Spark UI under "Storage"

Another problem in your code is that `count` on DataFrame does not compute the entire DataFrame because not all columns need to be computed for that. You can use `df.rdd.count()` to force the entire evualation (see [How to force DataFrame evaluation in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714291/how-to-force-dataframe-evaluation-in-spark)).

The question is why your first operation takes so long, even if no action is called. I think this is related to the caching logic (e.g. size estimations etc) being computed when calling cache (see eg. [Why is rdd.map(identity).cache slow when rdd items are big?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859386/why-is-rdd-mapidentity-cache-slow-when-rdd-items-are-big))